# Why is it called "galvanic" isolation?

Tags: isolation

What makes a device Galvanically isolated? This term is commonly used and yet I haven't been able to find a explanation clear enough that I can understand.

Take for example SMPS. In such device a transformer and opto-isolators are used ect.

Wiki says at the moment: "Galvanic isolation is a principle of isolating functional sections of electrical systems to prevent current flow; no direct conduction path is permitted."

Is that all? Does that mean anything magnetically or optically coupled is galvanically isolated? What if the DC GND of an AC/DC adapter is earth grounded ? Is it still galvanically isolated?

Most importantly Im wondering the difference between galvanically isolated and isolated? Why not call it electrically isolated or something similar?

Comment: You should ask Luigi.

Comment: "Why is this galvanic word nonsense that makes people confused?" Nonsense? Confusion? As PlasmaHH said, you should ask [Luigi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Galvani). Also, is it really confusing? I'm not confused, speak for yourself.

Comment: What did Luigi Galvani isolate? He discovered that the muscles of dead frogs' legs twitched when struck by an electrical spark. "somersetting" is mistype not nonsense dude.

Comment: Why not call it electrically isolated or somersetting(sic) like that?
Because it's called "galvanically isolated". You are thinking about electrical *insul*ation, which is not the same.

Comment: Did you check [the definition on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation) before you came here and stated that *nobody can explain*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the first Google result for the word galvanic gave a full explanation of what this means.

Comment: @Royc "Why is it called “galvanic” isolation?" is not the same question with "What does galvanic isolation mean?" Do you get the nuance?

Comment: The nuance that you haven't presented it as a (maybe?) legit question such as "why is this called galvanic isolation, as Luigi Galvani has done such and such which has a little to do with isolation *IMO*", but as a rant about something widely accepted among the community you are talking to.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you were walking down the street and someone would stop you and ask this question would you be able to answer? I guess some people are upset because they dont know the answer. And Im not planning to ask this question to a pharmacy student.

Comment: @doncarlos As I said, you might have a legit question in mind, but you formed it poorly and in somewhat offensive way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I got your point, the question sounds like a chat text.

Comment: The Celcius scale wasn't invented by Anders Celcius too and it was named after him.

Comment: It's not uncommon to honor some past scientists by giving their names to different terms which might not be directly invented by them.

Comment: I dont agree "galvanically" is like an adverb comes in front of the word that makes it sound like different than the word. Like saying "walking" and "slowly walking". One does not say celciusly measured-

Comment: The key word is the adjective Galvanic which is well defined as a electrical currents that are incurred by chemical actions. So the isolation must only prevent conductor contact and dielectric  breakdown to some level.  The opposite effect are electrodes that produce voltage from surface contact or a galvanic voltage

Comment: How about "ohmic resistance"?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Makes much sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh. resistance is not a verb.

Comment: @don carlos Sorry thought you were stressing the word galvanic.

Comment: I agree that the question wording isn't good, just rephrase it, and it will be good. But just my comments, this type of question is a result of critical thinking. Some people just accept whatever the terms given without even thinking. Sometimes terms are created because of its creator intention to rise up our intuition, hence intuitive. And it tremendously help us to learn the concept behind it. Just because of a single word. Picture speaks more than a thousand words as layman usually says. Ex: Resistor. Something that resist. In EE context, it resist currents. Very Intuitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key word is the adjective Galvanic which is well defined as a electrical currents that are incurred by chemical actions. So the isolation must only prevent conductor contact and dielectric breakdown to some level.

The opposite effect are electrodes that produce voltage from surface contact or a galvanic voltage.

The important thing to understand is that since line transformers were replaced with high frequency transformers for SMPS AC to DC converters, **galvanic isolation is inadequate for EMI isolation**. Since capacitive impedance does not induce a chemical current or dissimilar metal contact voltage, it is excluded, BUT, is the root cause of stray leakage currents and noise induced by SMPS as CM noise on floating DC chargers for portables.

Comment: Christ on drugs! What is it about you youngsters and the double spaces, spaces before period and spaces before question mark? Did some phone manufacturers recently update the keyboard functionality and failed?